# How do I install gcc 6.x on Oracle Solaris 11.2 x86 and CentOS 6.6 Final?

Tags: linux, unix, gcc, centos, solaris

I tried to install... but failed

1. `$ wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.2.0/gcc-6.2.0.tar.bz2`
2. `$ tar -jxvf gcc-6.2.0.tar.bz2`
3. `$ cd /home/logvadmin/gcc-6.2.0/`
4. `$ ./contrib/download_prerequisites`
5. `$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/gcc-6.2.0 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib`
6. `$ make`

In phase 6 Error

[Solaris]
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 27: Unexpected end of line seen

```
$ vi Makefile
```

26: ifeq (,$(.VARIABLES)) # The variable .VARIABLES, new with 3.80, is never empty.
27: $(error GNU make version 3.80 or newer is required.)
28: endif

user@solaris:~/gcc-6.2.0$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[CentOS]
It takes too long to build.
6 hour ??

I dont know what the problem is..

Comment: On Solaris, use `gmake`, not `make`. Build in parallel - `make -j<numcores>` to increase compilation speed.

Comment: Most standard Solaris utilities are POSIX-compliant and do not support non-standard arguments or behaviors.  Apparently GCC's `configure` is dependent upon GNU extensions to the standard `make` utility, so as noted, you have to use `gmake` in this case.

Comment: The question is kind of large. You should probably break it into separate questions. As for GCC 5... Installing GCC 5 on Solaris is kind of a pain. I was not able to do it. You can find a similar Q&A at [Where is GCC-5 after installing it on Solaris 11?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/339296/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Reply Thank you. It has helped a lot.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 2):

As the comments point out, use gmake.

For full details, see https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html

I fairly regularly build GCC from SVN head on Solaris 11.3 amd64, Fedora 24 x64 and FreeBSD 11 x64.

Firstly, I built and installed libgmp, lbmpc and libmpfr to ~/tools/lib. You may not need to do this if you are using a recent Linux or FreeBSB. On Solaris, third party freeware is often many years out of data.

My configure script for Solaris is:

```
#!/bin/ksh93

export LD_RUN_PATH=/export/home/paulf/tools/lib/lib
 ../configure --prefix=/export/home/paulf/tools/gcc --with-gmp=/export/home/paulf/tools/lib --with-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/gas --without-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld
```

My update & build script is:

```
#!/bin/ksh

export LD_RUN_PATH=~/tools/lib/lib

cd ~/scratch/gcc
svn up
cd build
gmake -j 4

if (( $? == 0 )) ; then
    print gmake succeeded
   gmake install
fi
```

Note that if you don't set the run path then the default GCC build won't set it and you will have an essentially broken compiler that needs LD_LIBRARY_PATH